# Table view cell not displaying all the text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

So I have a table cell which contains a multi line label supposed to display multiple lines of text.
This is what it looks like in Storyboard:
[image]

This is what it my cell looks like in the emulator:

[image]

The rest of the text is not showing. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to accomplish this

1- Give the label leading , trailing , top and bottom constraints **OR** top , bottom , centerX , fixedWidth/proportional

2- Make it's `.lines` property  = 0 to wrap

3- Don't put any height constraint to the label

4- Use automatic tableViewCells that means don't implement `heightForRowAt` and put this in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Thank you that worked :D

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong if you want to do multiple line height then make sure your number of line of `UILabel` property is `0` and dont give static height and also make sure you have to give four side constraints(top,left,bottom,right)

```
label.numberOfLines = 0


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 50
}
```